# Compare and contrast the possible values, probability distribution functions, expected values, and variances of the random Variables.

Tags: probability

Suppose a fair standard die is rolled twice, and the random variables X1 and X2 return the numbers on the faces that come up on the first and second rolls, respectively. Compare and contrast the possible values, probability distribution functions, expected values, and variances of the random variables Y = 2 * X1 and Z = X1 + X2

Answer (score 0):

For expected values, $E[cX]=cE[X]$. For variance, $Var[cX]=cVar[X]$, and $\sigma_X=\sqrt{Var[X]}$. When we add two random variables, $E[X_1+X_2]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]$, and the same can be said about variance:$Var[X_1+X_2]=Var[X_1]+Var[X_2]$. Therefore, $\sigma_{X_1+X_2}=\sqrt{Var[X_1]+Var[X_2]}$.